# Cart-button repeating confirmation 3x [added 'stay on product page after adding to cart'] possible theme conflict

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopping-cart

Just building site with Live theme and I've been trying to 'stay on product page after add to cart'.

This has been successful, and followed this tutorial (`https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/products/add-to-cart/stay-on-product-page-when-items-added-to-cart`)

The function works, but when adding/added to cart, it says>

"Adding...Adding...Adding..'

when finished adding product to cart it says> 'AddedAddedAdded'

1.Tried removing text from button but ends up blank.

2.There is guidance on the above tutorial for Debut theme, but not for Live theme. In part #6 of the tutorial, there is no

```
{% if cart.item_count > -1 %}
```

code in the header.liquid .

```
#product .ajaxified-cart-feedback:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
```

Tried this quick fix, it either didn't work, or I was putting it in the wrong .scss sheet. I only have theme.scss.liquid, or ajaxify.scss.liquid

I exepect the output to say> Added

Thanks in advance.